# how to put 2 consecutive output of DatePeriod with DateInterval of 1W to 2 variable using PHP

Tags: php

I have this code to get each week of the given dates

```
 $p = new DatePeriod
  (
      new DateTime(2018-01-1), 
      new DateInterval('P1W'), 
      new DateTime(2018-01-31)
  );

  foreach ($p as $w) 
  {
     $first_day = $w->format('Y-m-d');
  }
```

the outpout will be

```
2018-01-01,2018-01-08,2018-01-15,2018-02-01
```

my problem is ..how can I put 2 consecutive output in a variable using php and later to be use in sql?

like

```
2018-01-01 to 2018-01-08

2018-01-08 to 2018-01-15

2018-01-15 to 2018-02-01

$first_to_be_compare = '2018-01-01'
$date_to_compare =  '2018-01-08'
```

Comment: You can use '(date_column BETWEEN $from AND $to)'  in SQL

Comment: my bad..i editted my question..i already knew the sql part..my problem is how to get two dates and put it in a 2 variable using php

Comment: Please remove the MySQL tag

Comment: does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query

```
SELECT productName, productDesc FROM Products WHERE createdDate >= '2018-01-01' and createdDate < ' 2018-01-08'
```

Comment: my bad..i editted my question..i already knew the sql part..my problem is how to get two dates and put it in a 2 variable using php